# How do I get Tailwind and Vuetify to work together without causing style artifacts?

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I worked all day yesterday to finish a google cloud function to power an appointment maker vue component.  The last step is actually UI using the returned object.  I was planning on using the vuetify date/time pickers with allowed dates and times.

After spending much of today trying to add vuetify to an existing project to only use those to components, it is causing style errors with some classes(margin, etc) that are coming from main.sass.

I thought of adding a prefix to tailwind, but I don't have the time or inclination to go back to all of my components and files to add the prefix to all of my tailwind classes.

Is there something I can do to scope the vuetify classes/css so as not to cause problems outside of the two components I am trying to use?

Can I add the vuetify css after my tailwind is compiled and assembled so the tailwind classes win take precedent?

I don't have code to show as it is fairly straight forward.  I thought the google calendar API would be the hardest part of this component, but it is proving to be the easier.

Answer (score 16):

Tailwind allows you to prefix the generated classes in the configuration file. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration

Answer (score 5):

I know this is too late to answer but I'm writing this for other people like me who came up with this problem.

In order to add Vuetify to an existing project which is using Tailwind CSS without CSS class conflicting, You just need to activate `treeShake` in Vuetify options.

For example in a Nuxt project, add the below snippet in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {

// Other Configs

vuetify: {
    treeShake: true
  },
}
```

Comment: can you explain what does 'treeShake' do?

Comment: It removes unused CSS classes and styles so there will be no conflict between tailwind styles for classes like `.flex` and vuetify styles.

Comment: This is wrong. 
Event when using `treeSahake: true`, all basic styles will be imported

Answer (score 0):

According to the Vuetify docs: "*Install
webpack-plugin-vuetify
or
vite-plugin-vuetify
then enable it in your bundler configuration. Make sure the vuetify plugin comes after the vue plugin or it won’t work correctly*."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).