# How to install Vuetify in Laravel 8 with jetstream-inertia?

Tags: laravel, vuetify.js, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to install Vuetify on the latest Laravel versione (8) but I cannot do it. Seems it doesn't work even if the console doesn't show me any error.

That's my **resource/plugins/vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
// import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
// import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

My **webpack.mix.js** :

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
mix
.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
])
.webpackConfig({
  plugins: [
    new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
  ],
})
.browserSync('tb8.test');
```

The **app.js**

```
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue';

Vue.use(InertiaApp);
Vue.use(InertiaForm);
Vue.use(PortalVue);
Vue.use(vuetify);

const app = document.getElementById('app');

new Vue({
   vuetify,
   render: (h) =>
      h(InertiaApp, {
        props: {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        },
    }),
}).$mount(app);
```

and the **welcome.blade.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

   
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center sm:pt-0">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="hidden fixed top-0 right-0 px-6 py-4 sm:block">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Dashboard</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                </div>
            @endif

            <v-app>
                <v-main>
                    Hello World
                </v-main>
            </v-app>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me to find where is the mistake?
Thank you in advance

Valerio

Comment: I posted a tutorial: https://medium.com/@horaceh/laravel-jetstream-inertia-and-vuetify-8aa2ab3c1e41

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently Vuetify does not work with vue 3, so to install vuetify you have to go with vue 2. to do so:
we can install jetstream 2.1 which comes with vue 2. I have described installation process below:

Youtube video: https://youtu.be/V8_yLfNhg2I

1. To install laravel

   ```
    composer create-project laravel/laravel project_name
   ```
2. Now go to **composer.json** file and inside **require:{}** add just one line and rest of composer file should be same.

   **"laravel/jetstream": "2.1",**

after adding that "require" section of composer.json would look something like this:

```
 "require": {
            "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
            "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
            "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
            "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
            "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
            "laravel/jetstream": "2.1", 
          },
```

3. Now run **composer update**
4. Now run **php artisan jetstream:install inertia**
5. Now run **npm install**
6. Now run **npm install vuetify**
7. Go to **resources/css/app.css** and add following

   ```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900');

    @import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css');

    @import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
   ```
8. Now go to **resources/js/app.js** and add following code:

   ```
   require('./bootstrap');

   // Import modules...

   import Vue from 'vue';
   import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue';
   import PortalVue from 'portal-vue';
   //add these two line
   import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
   import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

   Vue.mixin({ methods: { route } });
   Vue.use(InertiaPlugin);
   Vue.use(PortalVue);
   //also add this line
   Vue.use(Vuetify);

   const app = document.getElementById('app');        

   new Vue({ 
        //finally add this line 
       vuetify: new Vuetify(), 
   render: (h) =>
       h(InertiaApp, {
           props: {
               initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
               resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
           },
       }),
       }).$mount(app);
   ```
9. Now run **npm run dev**

At this moment your vuetify will work!

To check whether **vuetify** with **inertia js** is working or not please follow:

1. Go to **resources/js/Pages** and create new file name **test.vue**
2. Add following code to **test.vue**

   ```
    <template>
      <v-app>
        <v-container>
            <v-btn>Click Me!</v-btn>
         </v-container>
      </v-app>
    </template>
   ```
3. Now run **npm run dev**
4. Now go to **route/web.php** and add

   ```
      Route::get('/', function () {
      return Inertia::render('test');
    });
   ```
5. Now **php artisan serve** to run in browser. and don't forget to add migrate and add database to **.env**

Comment: Hello Binaya.
Are you available to hire? 
You can reach me here, or twitter @ijpatricio

Comment: what about global scss so every components can access global variables? thanks

Comment: vuetify doesn't work on this. it does show but the classes are not there. I can't add classes like "white--text"

Comment: How to auto  reload the changes in vuetify?

Answer (score 17):

Fresh Laravel 8.12 + Jetstream + Inertia + VueJs + Vuetify

1. add to header the string of style in /resources/views/app.blade.php

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

2. add to /resources/js/app.js

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

and
`vuetify: new Vuetify(),` after 'new Vue({' like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

import { InertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue';
import { InertiaForm } from 'laravel-jetstream';
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue';

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

Vue.mixin({ methods: { route } });
Vue.use(InertiaApp);
Vue.use(InertiaForm);
Vue.use(PortalVue);
Vue.use(Vuetify)

const app = document.getElementById('app');

new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
            },
        }),
}).$mount(app);
```

3. After that, for example, you can create your vuetify component like this:
   `/resources/js/Components/NavigationDrawers.vue` with code from Vuetify labrory
4. init this vue-component in /resources/js/Pages/Dashboard.vue like
   `<navigation-drawers/>`
   with call
   `import NavigationDrawers from '@/Components/NavigationDrawers'`
   and
   `NavigationDrawers`
   in `<script>`

Example:

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <navigation-drawers/>

        ....
        ....
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import NavigationDrawers from '@/Components/NavigationDrawers'

    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'
    import Welcome from '@/Jetstream/Welcome'

    export default {
        components: {
            AppLayout,
            Welcome,
            NavigationDrawers,
        },
    }
</script>
```

It is help you for setting vuetify to your project.
Sass and other config you can config self.

[a screenshot example Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc13O.png)

[a screenshot example Navigation Drawer two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYyHd.png)

Comment: @Shturmavik you're an absolute gent and a scholar, thank you

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was needed!

Comment: Laravel Jetstream comes with tailwindcss. Afaik UI frameworks such as tailwindcss and vuetify are not meant to be mixed. How can one resolve this? There is for example the project [jetstrap](https://github.com/nascent-africa/jetstrap) to replace tailwindcss with bootstrap 4 in a Laravel Jetstream project. I would expect that one should have something similar to switch to vuetify. A question about this is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551434/how-do-i-get-tailwind-and-vuetify-to-work-together-without-causing-style-artifac . Any thoughts on how you would proceed?

Comment: doesn't work anymore :( jetstream / intertia now installs with vue v3+ and guess what...vuetify doesn't work with v3!

Comment: further to my last,if you're desperate then you can install a slightly older version of Jetstream:  composer require laravel/jetstream:v2.1

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify now has a Vue 3 branch (at the time of writing still in beta) The point about the clash with tailwind still stands although the problem is mostly manifests its self in terms of file size (of the css) Anyway to get things working in an install of Laravel (9) and Jetstream with Inertia you need to add vuetify

```
npm install vuetify@^3.0.7 --save
```

Then edit `resources/js/app.js`

by adding:

```
// Vuetify
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
})
```

and in the same file amending the createInertiaApp function set up so that Vue uses Vuetify

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
           ...
            .use(vuetify)
           ...
    },
});
```

You will then be able to use Vuetify components. You will probably want to set your own colours. There are two options SASS or javascript

here is an example of the Javascript option

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                dark: false,
                colors: {
                    primary:  "#415e96",
                    secondary: "#b89acc"
                }
            },
        },
    },
    components,
    directives,
}
```

)

More on this [here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/)

[Here](https://medium.com/@pierremriau/how-to-replace-vuetify-utility-classes-with-tailwindcss-9a3ebaa21f4f) is an (untested by me) article on removing the collisions between tailwind and Vuetify